# how to email auto-generated pdf

Tags: php, email, codeigniter, pdf, dompdf

as the title suggests, I am creating a pdf file (which works, prompts to be downloaded) and I wish to automatically email that pdf file to the user submitted email address.

I am using dompdf to generate the pdf file, and codeigniter as my framework.

how can I automatically email that pdf instead of downloading it and then email?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just save the file that is generated with dompdf and then you can attach it to an email using CodeIgniter's `attach()` method from the email class.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

Comment: can this be done automatically, or is it a task that a user must do?

Comment: You can handle this logic in the controller and automate everything so that the user doesn't have to download the file.  Checkout dompdf's docs on saving to disk and CI's docs on email attachments.

Comment: what would be the best way to delete the file afterwards?

Comment: Just store the name or path of the file that is being saved and use `delete_files()` from CI's file helper to remove it. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/file_helper.html

Answer (score 1):

Use dompdf to [write your PDF file to disk](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/FAQ). Then, [use the file as an attachment](http://www.geekology.co.za/blog/2009/06/sending-emails-with-attachments-using-php-mail-function/) and send the email.

Answer (score 0):

i am not familar with dompdf, but i would assume there is a function to return the pdf as a string. then use something like swiftmailer to send and email and attach the file as a string.

if your server does not have a lot of memory or the pdf if very large, then you can save the pdf as a tmp file first and attach it to an email, rather then keeping the pdf as a string in memory